# Positiveness of a real valued function of $n$ variables??

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Let $\{a_1,...,a_n\}$ be a set of $n$ non-negative parameters, we define $x^*=(x_i^*)_i$ as the $n$ dimensional vector with components: $$x_i^*=\frac{a_i^2}{\sum_j a_j^2}$$

Let $F:\Delta\to \mathbb{R}$ be the function given by $F(x)=\langle x-x^*,x-f(x)\rangle$, where $\Delta$ is the $n$ dimensional simplex ($\Delta=\{z\in \mathbb{R}^n: z_i\geq 0, \sum_i z_i=1\}$), and $f(x)$ has components: $$f_i(x)=\frac{a_i\sqrt{x_i}}{\sum_j a_j\sqrt{x_j}}$$.

Noticing that $f(x^*)=x^*$, prove (or find a counterexample ) that $F(x)\geq 0$.

Comment: So far, what I have proved that $\nabla F(x^*)=0$, and for the 2 dimensional case, the hessian matrix in that point appears to be positive definite. But checking the general $n\times n$ dimensional hessian is crazy  :S

Comment: It may help the following computations

$$\frac{\partial F(x)}{\partial x_j}= 2x_j-2\sum_{i\neq j} x_i-f_j(x)+\sum_{i\neq j}f_i(x)+\sum_i [(x_i^*-x_i)\frac{\partial f_i(x)}{\partial x_j}]-x_j^*+\sum_{i\neq j}x_i^*,$$

(note that $\frac{\partial F(x^*)}{\partial x_j}=0$),

And 

$$\frac{\partial^2 F(x)}{\partial x_j^2}=2[n-\frac{\partial f_j(x)}{\partial x_j}+\sum_{i\neq j}\frac{\partial f_i(x)}{\partial x_j}]+\sum_{i}(x_i^*-x_i)\frac{\partial^2 f_i(x)}{\partial x_j^2},$$

Where the last term is equals to zero if we evaluate in $x^*$.